# Task not found error in dataproc spark job

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

[image]> I am facing this issue intermittently in dataproc spark job in GCP for both long running job for 3-4 hrs and short running job 25-20 min. below is the spark configuration and dags conf of GCP cluster   `

```
spark.cores.max="80"
     master="yarn"
     spark.executor.memory="8G"
     spark.task.maxFailures="50"
     spark.driver.maxResultSize="10g"
     spark.hadoop.dfs.replication= "1"

     MASTER_MACHINE_TYPE = "n1-standard-4"
     WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE = "n1-standard-16"

     # Dataproc cluster definition
     CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
         "gce_cluster_config": {
             "subnetwork_uri": SUBNETWORK_URI,
             "internal_ip_only": True,
             "service_account" : GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
         },
         "master_config": {
             "num_instances": 3,
             "machine_type_uri": MASTER_MACHINE_TYPE,
             "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
             "image_uri" : IMAGE_URI
         },
         "worker_config": {
             "num_instances": 10,
             "machine_type_uri": WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE,
             "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
              "image_uri" : IMAGE_URI
          },
          "software_config": {
             "properties": {
                 "dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers": "true",
                 "yarn:yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class": 
     "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler",
                 "yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores": "48"
             }
         },
         "endpoint_config" : {
                "enable_http_port_access" : True
         },
         "lifecycle_config": {
             "idle_delete_ttl": {"seconds": 15*60},
              "auto_delete_ttl": {"seconds": 480*60},
         }
     }
```

`

Comment: Could you add the exact error message and where/when did you see the error?

Comment: @Dagang this is intermittent issue facing sometime I am not sure which situation causing this issue and I am just getting this "task not found" log in GCP UI with job status failed